# Where should I unregister a BroadcastReceiver if I intend on receiving broadcasts even when the app is in the background?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, onpause, ondestroy

For my purpose, I need to listen to CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE broadcasts as long as the app is running (foreground or background).

If I unregister in the onDestroy() method, I lose the receiver if I navigate back to the first activity, since the first activity is brought to the top.

If I unregister in onPause(), I can't listen to changes when the app is running in the background but not killed.

This is causing the receiver to leak intent when the app is killed forcefully.

What would an ideal solution for my case be?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/background-optimization.html#connectivity-action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the app is force stopped, it will leak no matter what you do.  When you're force stopped you don't get a chance to unregister anything.

But in the larger spirit of your question-  if you need a place to register a long term receiver and later unregister it, the answer is in a Service.

Comment: Thanks for that information, certainly pointed me in the right direction. Did not find that in other answers.

From a temporary workaround perspective, how "harmful" is leaking intent? Are there any side effects?

Comment: Not very harmful.  There's 2 real scenarios when these leaks happen:  you still needed the receiver and were force closed.  In this case, no harm done.  Or you didn't need the receiver and should have unregistered it in the past.  In this case, no harm to your app, but your app was using resources it didn't need to use processing events on that receiver.  Harm is cpu cycles wasted and some battery power.  So minimal harm there.

Comment: Great, that solves my problem.

Will read more into services and trying them out for my use-case.

Thanks a lot!